# How to access redirected URL response from .POST HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to connect to a payment server, which is supposed to redirect me to another URL other than the one I have in my code.

So I used Alamofire (.POST request) to connect to the server but I always enter the error case for "too many HTTP redirects" code=1007

And I know that the server should return that, What I need is to print the URL the server tried to redirect me to in my xcode console.

I have tried to use:

```
print(response.response?.allHeaderFields)
```

But didn't help in the output, Couldn't access the redirected URL.

```
let urlString = "http://www.gazdev.tk/PHP_VPC_3Party_Order_DO.php"
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
    response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print(response.response)
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        print(response.response)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I get this as print statement:

> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"

Answer (score 0):

I think `response.response?.url` is what you want,eg:

```swift
AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint("redirect = \(response.response?.url)")
}
```